# Laravel Postgres SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7 ERROR: zero-length delimited identifier at or near """"

Tags: laravel

I am trying to seed data using laravel but i keep getting this error despite trying to replace all `""` with `''`

My code

```
foreach ($groupPermissionsStructure as $groupName => $permissionStructure) {

            $group = collect($groups->where('alias', $groupName)->first());

            if ($group->isNotEmpty()) {

                $group = Group::firstOrCreate([
                    'name' => $group['name'],
                    'alias' => strtolower($group['alias']),
                    'description' => $group['description'],
                    'organization_id' => 1,
                    'status' => 1,
                ]);

                $names = explode(" ", $group['name']);

                $domain = str_replace([" ", "-", "_"], "", $groupName);

                User::firstOrCreate([
                    'first_name' => $names[0],
                    'last_name' => isset($names[1]) ? $names[1] : $names[0],
                    'email' => $domain . '@test.com',
                    'email_verified_at' => Carbon::now(),
                    'status' => config('constants.status.active'),
                    'group_id' => $group->id,
                    'password' => Hash::make($domain)
                ]);
            }
```

My error

```
SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7 ERROR:  zero-length delimited identifier at or near """"
LINE 1: select * from ""."groups" where ("name" = $1 and "alias" = $...
                      ^ (SQL: select * from ""."groups" where ("name" = Super Administrator and "alias" = super_administrator and "description" = Overall system super administrator and "organization_id" = 1 and "status" = 1) and ""."groups"."deleted_at" is null limit 1)
```

Comment: This error occured because i had not specified my "DB_SCHEMA" in my env file, despite the fact that the database credentials were correct

Comment: This helped :                                                  
```php artisan cache:clear ```
 ```php artisan config:cache ```
```php artisan config:clear```  ```composer dump-autoload```